# iOS core plot- plotting Labels on x axis non major and minor points

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using core plot for iOS.
Initially not showing anything on X axis.
But when the user taps on any data point, I want to show a label on the X value of the point on X axis.
I could't find anything on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example apps included with Core Plot, especially the *Plot Gallery*. It has several examples of adding an annotation to the plot in response to the user tapping a data point.